# Problem with sending Invite in Linphone 4.x

Tags: sip, linphone, invite, linphone-sdk

I used to SDK Linphone version 3.3.0 before and now I want to update to the latest version but I have a problem with the new version:

In Linphone 3.3.0 when you send an INVITE message and server responds with 302, Linphone automatically retries the request with a new INVITE to the server that is specified in Contact header field of 302. It sends a completely new INVITE with no Proxy-Authorization.

In Linphone 4.x. when Linphone retries the request (to a 302) it sends a Proxy-Authorization header which belongs to the previous INVITE and contains address and information of that server. This causes the server to respond with a 403 Not Relaying!